# String Split into list R

Tags: r

Extract words from a string and make a list in R

```
str <- "qwerty keyboard"
result <- strsplit(str,"[[:space:]]")
```

What I get was..(down below)

```
result
[[1]]
[1] "qwerty" "keyboard"
```

What I need is..(down below)

```
result
[[1]]
[1] "qwerty"
[[2]]
[1] "keyboard"
```

[OR]

```
result
[[1]]
[1] "qwerty"
[2] "keyboard"
```

I am looking for a solution, if someone knows please post your solution here.
thanks in advance..

Comment: You actually got what you asked for already. It's the same as the last example you gave, it just prints differently.

Comment: You can use `as.list(scan(text=str, what='', sep=' '))`

Answer (score 18, accepted):

try:

```
str <- "qwerty keyboard"
result_1 <- strsplit(str,"[[:space:]]")[[1]][1]
result_2 <- strsplit(str,"[[:space:]]")[[1]][2]
result <- list(result_1,result_2)
```

Or

```
as.list(strsplit(str, '\\s+')[[1]])
```

Comment: I did like this `as.list(strsplit(str, '\\s+'))` but i did't get..thank you

Comment: @VinodhVelumayil  You have to use `[[1]]` to make it a vector and then change it to list with `as.list`

Comment: Nice solution.`as.vector(strsplit(str, '\\'))` worked great as well.

Answer (score 1):

```
as.list(unlist(strsplit(str, '[[:space:]]')))
```

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to `strsplit()`, you can make a list out of the result from `scan()`.

```
as.list(scan(text=str, what=""))
# Read 2 items
# [[1]]
# [1] "qwerty"
#
# [[2]]
# [1] "keyboard"
```