# Multiple list objects as a character variable in df. How to convert into original df with R?

Tags: r, list, character, data-manipulation

I have a problem with my dataset containing character variables that are actually a list of values which I would want to convert into dataframe. Orginal dataframe consists several 1000 of rows.

I would like to split to a list objects in order to convert lists into dataframe (long format), but I lack some skills with list-objects and splitting characters.

Reproducible example:

```
id <- c("112")
name <- c( "{\"dog\", \"cat\",\"attashee\"}")
value <- c("{\"21000\", \"23400\", \"26800\"}")
test <- data.frame(id, name, value)
test
```

I would like have an outcome like this:

```
id <- c("112","112","112")
name <- c( "dog", "cat","attashee")
value <- c("21000", "23400", "26800")
test1 <- data.frame(id, name, value)
test1
```

I suppose, I need to start by erasing first and the last characters `{` and `}`:

```
test$name <- gsub("{", "", test$name, fixed=TRUE)
test$name <- gsub("}", "", test$name, fixed=TRUE)
```

I have tried to use these [string-split-into-list-r](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30474729/string-split-into-list-r), [convert-a-list-formatted-as-string-in-a-list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49027246/convert-a-list-formatted-as-string-in-a-list) and [convert-a-character-variable-to-a-list-of-list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43976104/convert-a-character-variable-to-a-list-of-list),

```
test$name <- strsplit(test$name, ',')[[1]]
```

but I get an error message(when I try this to first row of my original data): `"replacement has 91 rows, data has 1"`.

The fact is, I´m pretty lost here as I would need to convert name and value columns simultaneously (and I don´t know how to convert even one column).

All the help and advises are more than appreciated.

Comment: Try `sapply(test$name, function (x) strsplit(x, ",")[[1]])`

Comment: Thanks for the tip! I did use sapply, but unfortunately I couldn´t solve the problem 100%. I will post the solution if I can find one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```
id <- c("112")
name <- c( "{\"dog\", \"cat\",\"attashee\"}")
value <- c("{\"21000\", \"23400\", \"26800\"}")
test <- data.frame(id, name, value)
test

id <- rep(test$id, length(name))
name <- gsub("\\{", '', name)
name <- gsub("\\}", '', name)
name <- gsub('"', '', name)
name <- gsub('\\s+', '', name)
name <- strsplit(name, ',')[[1]]
value <- gsub("\\{", '', value)
value <- gsub("\\}", '', value)
value <- gsub('"', '', value)
value <- gsub('\\s+', '', value)
value <- strsplit(value, ',')[[1]]
test1 <- data.frame(id, name, value)
test1
```

Comment: Thanks for the help and advice!

Answer (score 0):

I would parse and evaluate:

```
id <- c("112", "113")
name <- c( "{\"dog\", \"cat\",\"attashee\"}", "{\"dog\", \"cat\",\"attashee\"}")
value <- c("{\"21000\", \"23400\", \"26800\"}", "{\"21001\", \"23401\", \"26801\"}")
test <- data.frame(id, name, value)

clean_parse_eval <- function(x) {
  eval(parse(text = gsub("\\}", ")", gsub("\\{", "c\\(", x))))
}
```

We then need a split-apply-combine approach to do this for every row. Of course, this isn't very fast.

```
library(data.table)
setDT(test)

test[, lapply(.SD, clean_parse_eval), by = id]
#    id     name value
#1: 112      dog 21000
#2: 112      cat 23400
#3: 112 attashee 26800
#4: 113      dog 21001
#5: 113      cat 23401
#6: 113 attashee 26801
```

Obviously, it would be better to avoid producing such malformed data to begin with.

Comment: if you do `name <- do.call(paste0, name)` and then replace the`}{` with a `,`  by doing `name <-  gsub("}{", ",", name, fixed=TRUE)` then you fall in the original case, so the second part of your code woudn't be necessary.

Comment: @Batato The problem is that the ID needs to be recycled.

Comment: I agree with you Roland - This is really stupid situation. This a problem because names/values are gathered under single row and under one variable in postgre database.

Comment: @Thomas You should solve this during the data import from the database.

Comment: @Roland You are probably right, I´m amused why this kind of variable even exists in db if it´s so troublesome to use.

Comment: all variables are factor here and value wasn't converted

Answer (score 0):

This can do the job for you, no libraries, some explanation in within lines

```
id <- c("112")
name <- c( "{\"dog\", \"cat\",\"attashee\"}")
value <- c("{\"21000\", \"23400\", \"26800\"}")

convert <- function(col, isFloat = FALSE) {
  # remove the two {} characters
  col <- gsub("{", "", gsub("}", "", col, fixed=TRUE), fixed=TRUE)
  # create a vector with the right content
  ans <- eval(parse(text = paste0('c(', col, ')')))
  if (isFloat)
    unlist(lapply(ans, as.numeric))
  else
    ans
}

test <- data.frame(convert(id), convert(name), convert(value, TRUE))
# optionally you can fix the names here
names(test) <- c('id', 'name', 'value')
# final result
test
```

Notice that you can use the convert function to add more columns to your dataframe if you need to.

If your `name` variable for example have 1000 more entries, then do `name <- do.call(paste0, name)` to put all into a single string and then replace the`}{` with a `,`  by doing `name <-  gsub("}{", ",", name, fixed=TRUE)` then you fall in the original case, and then the same logic applies.

Comment: This desn't work if the input has more than one row.

Comment: I'm using the format he has shown, for what he has, it works.

Comment: Yes, and I posted exactly the same answer some minutes ago, but I deleted because they write "Orginal dataframe consists several 1000 of rows."

Comment: I think he is referring to the amount of "rows" inside the strings, nevertheless I have commented the answer accordingly.

Comment: I apologize for the confusion. I meant how many rows I have in df. Roland is correct with his interpretation. But again, sorry for ambiguous information. Roland is also right saying this won´t work with several rows with different id´s. I´m still very grateful for all the tips. They are still very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

This will work for one column. I tried this for your **name** object and it does the job

```
library(stringr)
library(dplyr)
name <- c( "{\"dog\", \"cat\",\"attashee\"}")
x <- as.data.frame(name) %>% mutate_each(funs(str_replace_all(., "\"", "")))
result <- strsplit(x$name,"![a-z]")[[1]]
result <- gsub('\\{', '', result)
result <- gsub('\\}', '', result)
result <- strsplit(as.character(result), split = ',', fixed = TRUE)[[1]]
result <- gsub(" +", "", result)
str(result)
#chr [1:3] "dog" "cat" "attashee"
```

Comment: Welcome. Is it working with your setup? Please accept/upvote answers if they resolve your problem. This will help others facing the same issue. Thanks.